# Why can't this method access the session?

Tags: session, laravel, laravel-5

I have a session containing some data that I access throughout several methods in my controller with no trouble. But one method in particular has problems.

I have made a little booking system. On completion of a booking, I call a function to send an e-mail to myself and the customer:

```
public function complete(Request $request)
    {
        $details = Session::get('details');

        // send emails: call sendConfirmationEmail(to address, using this view)
        $this->sendConfirmationEmail(env('EMAIL'), 'emails.ourconfirmation');
        $this->sendConfirmationEmail($details->booker_email, 'emails.bookerconfirmation');

        return view('booking/complete');
    }

private function sendConfirmationEmail($to,$view)
    {
        $from = env('OFFICE_EMAIL');
        $to_address = $to;

        $details = Session::get('details');
        $instance = Session::get('instance');

        Mail::queue($view, compact(['details','instance']), function($message) use ($to){
            $message->from(env('OFFICE_EMAIL'))
                    ->to($to)
                    ->subject('Thanks for booking');
        });
    }
```

First I got an error accessing a non-object in my e-mail view. So to test it I just set the `sendConfirmationEmail` function to return `$instance` - blank page. Then I tested it by commenting out the function call in `complete()` and returning `$instance` there. No problem, there's a nice shiny session full of data. Then I tried passing `$instance` from `complete()` to `sendConfirmationEmail()` and returning it: again, blank page. Why can't `sendConfirmationEmail` 'see' my session?!

Comment: i assume you see a 500 error page; what's the error in the laravel log or error log of the site? I think it has something to do with parameters, but can't be sure without the exact error log

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, Sessions are for using across HTTP requests, not across functions in PHP. You are trying the use Sessions as global variables.

You can simply capture `details` and `instance` session data in the `complete` function, and then pass them along as parameters for the `sendConfirmationEmail()` function.